# For what $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ the solution set of linear system is Sub-space two-dimensional of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> For what $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ the solution set of linear system is Sub-space two-dimensional of $\mathbb{R}^4$
>
> $$
> \left\{ 
> \begin{array}{r}
> x+y+z=0 \\ 
> -x+y+az=0 \\ 
> -x+y+z=b
> \end{array}
> \right. 
> $$

---

First I tried to find the solutions set :

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&0\\ -1&1&a&0\\ -1&1&1&b\end{pmatrix}...\rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&0\\ \:0&2&a+1&0\\ \:0&0&-a+1&b\end{pmatrix}$$

so how I can continue from here ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is a vector subspace if an only if $b=0$.

If this be the case, by the rank-nullity theorem, it is a two-dimensional subspace if and only if the matrix has rank $2$. Can you conclude?

Comment: so there are no $a,b$ so that rank A = 1 ?

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistyping. See my updated answer.  However, in my opinion, you should check your formulation. Is the system really defined on $\mathbf R^4$?

Comment: in the question that I have that's how it is written but this make no sense on $R^4$

Comment: It makes sense, but it's strange. Also, are you sure ‘subspace’ here does not mean ‘*affine* subspace’?

Comment: no it say's subspace not affine subspace

Comment: In this case, your augmented matrix  should be 3 × 5.